# android can't use getLayoutInflater in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, layout-inflater

I am using fragments and i trying to build a list i am getting from the database. Everything seems to be fine except for the following piece of code

```
listadapter = new charitylist(this, getLayoutInflater());
```

I already set the layout inflater here

```
LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
```

But i don't have any idea how to use the layoutinflater lf int the listadapter.

This is the full code

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = lf.inflate(R.layout.activity_charity, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.charityList);

        listadapter = new charitylist(this, getLayoutInflater());

        listView.setAdapter(listadapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                //String trackName = listadapter.getItem(position).optString("track_name", "");


            }

        });

        setType = "favourite";

        getlist(setUrl, setType);

        return view;
    }
```

I have no idea how to get this working. I tried several things to get this to work. But i need to initiate the adapter.

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LayoutInflater inflater` is already provided in `onCreateView` of `Fragment`. Why don't you use like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_charity, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.charityList);
    listadapter = new charitylist(getActivity(), inflater);
 ...
```

Comment: the problem i am faving is the following: getlayoutinflater bundle in fragment connot be applied in the following line istadapter = new charitylist(this, getLayoutInflater());

Comment: @carlosx2, check updated answer.. You can pass that inflater to `charitylist`.

Comment: @carlosx2, great. Can you also [accept and upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) my answer.

Comment: already upvoted, just had to accept it :). thanks for the help.